# How to debug heap in a Native Activity on Android?

Tags: android, c++, memory, heap-memory, native-activity

Is there a way to debug the heap in C++ in a Native Activity for overrun/underrun errors?  There is zero Java usage in my application.

Something I know about is the `MALLOC_CHECK_` which doesn't seem to be applicable to GNU libstdc++.  I'm looking for something that would work in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is to get my iOS build working and turn on all the memory diagnosis tools.  Albeit this is not an ideal situation for most, it solved the issue I was having.